# Add Hour with date time then compare this time with current time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using one temp table to compare between two column using dateadd() for adding Hour. but in select dateadd() I am getting only one result!

How to get all record values?

```
 DECLARE @temp TABLE (
    ArmouryIssueId INT
    ,Estimatedtime INT
 )

INSERT INTO @temp (
    ArmouryIssueId
    ,Estimatedtime
)
SELECT ArmouryIssueId ,EstimatedTime FROM [ArmouryIssueGun]

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
    ,@EndDate DATETIME
    ,@ExpectedTime INT

SELECT @StartDate = CreatedOn FROM [ArmouryIssueGun] AS aig
INNER JOIN @temp TEMP ON aig.ArmouryIssueId = TEMP.ArmouryIssueId

SELECT @ExpectedTime = Estimatedtime FROM @temp

SELECT dateadd(HOUR, @ExpectedTime, @StartDate) AS time_added
    ,@StartDate AS curr_date
```

Comment: Can you explain your question little bit more with sample data

Comment: add table strucutre , table values and expected result plz

Comment: I have one table where 2 column name CreatedOn and EstimateTime(hr) are there. i am trying to add EstimateTime with CreatedOn and compare this add result with current time.

Comment: Your should write what is `date` added `time` `compare` and excepted result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,Estimatedtime,CreatedOn) AS TIME_ADDED,
CREATEDON AS CURR_DATE FROM [ARMOURYISSUEGUN]
```